# How to copy files from a path found in env strings?

Tags: nsis

trying this fails NSIS during installer building... in any way I try t put it.

```
readEnvStr $R0 "QT_PATH"
File $R0\bin\QtCore4.dll 
File $R0\bin\QtGui4.dll
```

During installer building, i'd like to include files from a path encoded in the environment string QT_PATH. how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File instruction takes a path on the local system you are compiling on. SetOutPath is used to set the destination directory at run-time:

```
Section
ReadEnvStr $R0 "QT_PATH"
# Might be a good idea to validate the path here and fall back to some other location if necessary
SetOutPath "$R0\bin"
File "c:\myinstallersourcefiles\QtCore4.dll"
...
```

Or the path on your local system: `File "$%QT_PATH%\bin\QtCore4.dll"`